# Probability of getting a sum of 14 when rolling 11 dice

Tags: probability, dice

So, this is a probability and combinatorics problem... I'm not sure how to solve this.

I assume that in P(A) = m/n, n is 6^11, but I don't know how to calculate the number of ways to get a sum of 14 when rolling 11 dice.

Remember, I should be able to solve this with the knowledge of basic probability, because this is a high school-level problem.

Comment: First, work out all the ways to get 11 dice to add up to 14. You could have 10 ones and a four, or 9 ones, a two, and a three, or 8 ones and three twos, and that's it, right? Then figure how many ways each of those three outcomes can occur.

Comment: This is nitpicking at details, but there do exist [dice that aren't fair](http://www.shapeways.com/product/QQSRS6S92/weighted-dice-set?li=gmerchant&ca=gp&ct=pla&cr=catchall&gclid=CNyA8LjSqsUCFRc8gQodh50Aqw), [dice with unusual number of sides](http://www.coolstuffinc.com/p/147197?gclid=CMiTztTSqsUCFaVj7AoduXYALA), and [dice whose faces are not the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Backgammon_DoublingCube.jpg).  This is all important information that should be mentioned in a problem statement.

Comment: @ JMoravitz how about we agree on a "common sense" definition of a die, unless otherwise stated..?  Advantage would be to keep the problem statements shorter.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that those are fair dice, probably because I've done so many of these problems that it's considered a fair die unless stated otherwise :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the dice are all standard six-sided dice.

The *minimum* sum is $11$, which you can get only one way.

To get a sum of $12$, you have to roll something greater than $1$ on
at least one die. But in fact if you roll $2$ on one die then you have to
roll $1$ on every other die or you'll be over $12$.
You cannot roll anything over $2$ or the sum will be too large.
So the number of ways to do this is the number of ways to choose one die
out of $11$ (choose the die that will show a $2$).

To get a sum of $13$, you have more choices. 
You can roll one $3$, but then all other rolls have to be $1$.
Alternatively, if you roll a $2$ one one die, you must roll a $2$ on one
other die and $1$ on every die in the remaining nine dice.
You cannot roll anything over $3$.
So the total number of ways to add up to $13$ is
the number of ways to show exactly one $3$ and ten $1$s on $11$ dice,
plus the number of ways to show exactly two $2$s and nine $1$s on $11$ dice.

The number of ways to roll a sum of $14$ is just another counting exercise
requiring a little more work than the sum $13$.

Comment: That's correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to realize that a sum of 14 with 11 dice is quite low...

That's only possible with:

A) a subset of one die showing 4 and the other ten all showing 1

or

B) a subset consisting of one die showing 3 and one showing 2, and the other nine all showing 1

or

C) a subset of three dice showing 2, the other eight all showing 1

(To see how many ways each of these can happen may be bit easier if you imagine the dice are thrown one by one)

A can happen in 11 ways (1st die one, or second die one, or 3rd die one...)

To see how many ways you can get to B, note that the die that shows three can again be at 11 positions (1st, 2nd...), once the position for that die is "chosen", you have 10 positions left for the die that shows 2, so you have $11\cdot10$ possibilities.

This is nothing else but applying the formula for the number of *$k$ permutations of $n$* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n):

$_nP_k=\cfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

where $n$ is the total number of dice, and $k$ are the ones you "choose" or "label" as belonging to the subset.

For C, assume as an intermediate step, that the three dice showing 2 each had a different colour.  Then the number of distinguishable outcomes would be analogous to B: $11\cdot 10\cdot9$.

With different colours, e.g. if the "first" three dice would show 2, and they were blue, red, green, and with chosing the position for the blue one first, then red, then green, there would be three options to place the blue one. Once that is done, two positions are left to place the red one and one place remains for the green one.

So there would be $k!$ ways to get three times 2 with the "first" three dice.

But as the dice do not have different colours here, these are not distinct outcomes (equivalent to the dice showing one in the remainder of the sequence not being distinguished) .  In the total number of ("distinguishable") possible results, $6^{11}$, the result with three dice showing 2 at the three "first" positions is ("only") included once.  So by calculating C with $_nP_k=\cfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, we would count every distinct outcome with three dice showing 2 not once, but $k!$ times - to correct for this, divide the result by $k!$ to get

$_nC_k=\binom{n}{k}=\cfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

which is the formula for the number of  *"$k$-combinations"* in a set with a subset of $k$ distinct elements. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Here:  $_nC_k=\binom{11}{3}=\cfrac{11!}{3!(8)!}=\cfrac{11\cdot10\cdot9}{6}=165$

In summary, you have $11+110+165=286$ ways of getting 14 with 11 dice.

As you correctly stated, any specific distinguishable outcome has a probability of $\cfrac{1}{6^{11}}$.

Hence the probability to get 14 with eleven dice is $\cfrac{286}{6^{11}}$.

(=$0.00008\%$)

Comment: You have overcounted Case C: If (for example), dice $2, 5, 7$ are $2$'s, you will have counted that collection six times, one for each ordering of $2, 5, 7$.

Comment: @ Brian Tung - thanks - I'll have to think about that.  What I thought was, do we not also count every possible sequence separately in the denominator of the probability?  would it then not be inconsistent to use only the number of combinations in the numerator?

Comment: Let's look at a simpler case.  Suppose you have three dice, and you want to know how likely it is to roll a $5$.  The case you want to consider consists of rolling two $2$'s and a $1$.  Out of $6^3 = 216$ rolls of the dice, do you expect to see that $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ times?  Or $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ times?

Comment: @ Brian Tung  still thinking about that.  am a bit confused.  sorry.  if the question had been rolling one dice eleven times, would that have changed your comment?

Comment: I don't see how it would, since one gets the same results either way.

Comment: @ Brian Tung - Many thanks! Think I got it now, and edited the answer accordingly. I now get the same result as James Pak.

Comment: You misquoted me.  According to me, you should see a $5$ a total of $6$ times out of $6^3 = 216$ rolls, but you should see a $5$ as two $2$'s and a $1$ only $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ times.  To pick an even simpler example, by your line of reasoning, with a roll of two dice, you would expect to see a pair of $2$'s $2 \cdot 1 = 2$ times, but in fact, they only occur $\binom{2}{2} = 1$ time.

Comment: You took out a vital part of my quote.  The fact that you think it is immaterial is probably why you don't get it, though.  You replaced "getting a 5 by two 2's and a 1" with just "getting a 5."  However, I think someone else should try explaining it, because explanation doesn't make sense to you (which is no one's fault).  Or, alternatively, you could try simulating it and see how often it actually happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23519/discussion-between-brian-tung-and-user70160).

Comment: @ Brian Tung  many thanks for taking the time to discuss this with me!  I deleted my comments to not confuse others and voted all your comments as useful.  As discussed my mistake was not to see that $6^3$ does not include indistinguishable permutations.  My confusion started, because I saw $\binom{6}{3}$ and thought this is used because order is ignored, which would be wrong, but it is actually used here to adjust for indistinguishable permutations - as I had ironically explained in my answer to the original question... So this is consistent with $6^3$ for the total.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the problem to

$$1+1+ ... + 1$$

And as noted, the sum is at least 11, so there are at least eleven $1$s. Now the problem is to add three more $1$s to the sum. Consider the following three cases:

$(1)$ Number of one $4$ and ten $1$s $= 11$

$(2)$ Number of one $3$, one $2$ and nine $1$s $=\binom{11}{2}*2!$

$(3)$ Number of three $2$s and eight $1$s $= \binom{11}{3}$

Thus the probability is $$\frac{(11+110+165)}{6^{11}}=\frac{286}{362797056}$$

Comment: James, could you please explain the multiplication with $2!$ in case 2)?

Comment: First choose 2 positions from 11 for the $3$ and $2$, and there are ${11 \choose 2}$ ways to do so. Mind that, for instance, $32111111111$ is different from $23111111111$, so in total there are ${11 \choose 2}*2!$ ways. Actually it is equal to $11*10$, similar to your idea.

Comment: many thanks!  that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! It all makes sense now...